# set dynamic content on slider div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use one of these two jquery plugins ([awkward](http://www.awkwardgroup.com/sandbox/awkward-showcase-a-jquery-plugin/)/[Coda Slider 3](http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/)) for sliding DIV content.
Everything works fine until I am try to set dynamic content (with js) after the plugin object has been created.
The DIVs show only content that loaded before the plugin created.
Any ideas or other DIV slider plug-in's for this goal.
Thanks.

the ajax working perfect I have checked it.
this is the load function for coda slider  `$('#slider-id').codaSlider();`
and for "awkward" :

```
$(window).ready(function () {
        $("#showcase").awShowcase(
    {
        content_width: 700,
        fit_to_parent: false,
        auto: false,
        interval: 3000,
        continuous: false,
        loading: true,
        tooltip_width: 200,
        tooltip_icon_width: 32,
        tooltip_icon_height: 32,
        tooltip_offsetx: 18,
        tooltip_offsety: 0,
        arrows: true,
        buttons: true,
        btn_numbers: false,
        keybord_keys: true,
        mousetrace: false, /* Trace x and y coordinates for the mouse */
        pauseonover: true,
        stoponclick: true,
        transition: 'fade', /* hslide/vslide/fade */
        transition_speed: 500,
        transition_delay: 300,
        show_caption: 'onhover', /* onload/onhover/show */
        thumbnails: true,
        thumbnails_position: 'outside-last', /* outside-last/outside-first/inside-last/inside-first */
        thumbnails_direction: 'horizontal', /* vertical/horizontal */
        thumbnails_slidex: 0, /* 0 = auto / 1 = slide one thumbnail / 2 = slide two thumbnails / etc. */
        dynamic_height: true, /* For dynamic height to work in webkit you need to set the width and height of images in the source. Usually works to only set the dimension of the first slide in the showcase. */
        speed_change: false, /* Set to true to prevent users from swithing more then one slide at once. */
        viewline: false /* If set to true content_width, thumbnails, transition and dynamic_height will be disabled. As for dynamic height you need to set the width and height of images in the source. */
    });
    });
```

Comment: You're going to have to show us some of the code you're referring to. What are the functions you're using to load the slider initially? What are the Ajax calls that are intended to load additional content?

Comment: there are 100's of content slider plugins... look for one with the features you need and docs that tell you how to add content. People here aren't going to guess what plugins you are trying, or do the documentation search for you

Comment: Dear charlietfl, you can say it for any question in stack.I don't expect nobody to do reasrech for me!!! I am trying to get help from developers experience maby someone know about issue in this area or know this specific plugins or did similar use in other plugin.
more over I have tried 4 similar plugins and in all there is the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin Batdorf has improved on the *Coda Slider* with something called *Liquid Slider* which supports ajax and callbacks.

Read a tutorial on it [here](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/tutorials/dynamically-add-content-to-a-panel-when-clicked-using-ajax/)

And it is available on [github](https://github.com/KevinBatdorf/liquidslider).